# bne instruction in cpu simulator not working

Tags: c, assembly, cpu, mips, cpu-architecture

I am trying to write a cpu simulator. But, it doesnt seem to function as expected when bne instruction is encountered. bne performs the same as bqe. bqe seems to be working fine though:

```
Mux2_32(mbranchAddress, pcPlus4, branchAddress, AND2_1(zero, branch));
Mux2_32(pc, mbranchAddress, jumpAddress, jump);

if(!strcmp(opcode, "000101")&& !strcmp(branch, "1")){ /*bne instruction, ("000101" is the opcode for bne)*/
Mux2_32(mbranchAddress, pcPlus4, branchAddress, AND2_1(NOT_1(zero), branch));
Mux2_32(pc, mbranchAddress, jumpAddress, jump);
}
```

"branch" is the flag raised when the instruction is a branch instruction. zero is the single bit alu output

MUX2_32(a, b, c, d) works as follows:
a=b if d=0
a=c if d=1

where a, b and c are 32 bits long and d is a single bit.

Could someone please point out why beq instruction works fine but bne doesn't. Thanks

Comment: What language is this? C++?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: its in C

Comment: Then I'd say your `==` comparisons for strings are a bit off.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson : I changed opcode=="000101" to opcode=='000101'. Still works the same :(

Comment: Should probably be `if(!strcmp("000101", opcode) && !strcmp("1", branch)) {`

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I already tried that :). But no luck :(

Comment: Just wondering; why would you use text representations of binary numbers to store machine code? That seems very inefficient in just about every way possible.

Comment: @Michael : It is a part of my assignment. And I have to represent each instruction in 32 bit MIPS form. So, I though using strings would be the way to go. Is there another efficient way? If so, I am very curious to know about it. I agree it has made things complicated.

Comment: The simplest would be to just use plain binary. That is, store each 32-bit word exactly as-is, instead of converting them to strings.

Comment: How can you use `branch` as both a boolean/numerical value (`AND2_1(zero, branch)`) **and** a string (`strcmp(branch, "1")`)? One of them if most likely wrong

Answer (score 1):

C does not support binary number constants. 000101 is an octal number with value 65... and '000101' is a 64 bit wide multichar constant. You need to use hex numbers, that is opcode 000101 in hex is 0x5...

Comment: I already tried using strcmp, sorry i did not update the question. But this still does not help.

Comment: Both GCC and clang support binary constants of the form `0bxxxxxxx` as an extension.